# openvpn allow only 1 connection with ifconfig-pool-persist option

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, ip

I have a openvpn server with the following config:

```
ca ...
cert ...
key ...
dh ...


local ...
port 40000
proto udp
dev tun
server 192.168.100.0 255.255.252.0
ifconfig-pool-persist "/etc/openvpn/ipp.txt"
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
keepalive 10 120
client-to-client


tun-mtu 1500
fragment 1300
mssfix

--script-security 2


--client-connect "/etc/openvpn/vpn_conn_event.py"
--client-disconnect "/etc/openvpn/vpn_conn_event.py"

# Log
status "openvpn-status.log" 
log "openvpn.log" 
#log-append "openvpn.log" 
verb 3
```

It works nice and keeps the ip adresses persistent, but occasionally the address for a client changes which is very upsetting. I traced this down further and found that it this happens when (for whatever reason) a client openes a new connection with the old one not beeing disconnected yet. Here's a log:

```
| DATE                | Cert | assigned IP    | Event     |
| 25/04/2018 03:01:46 | abc  | 192.168.101.18 | CONNECT   |
| 25/04/2018 04:04:54 | abc  | 192.168.100.66 | CONNECT   |
| 25/04/2018 04:08:42 | abc  | 192.168.101.18 | DISCONNECT|
| 25/04/2018 11:09:48 | abc  | 192.168.100.66 | DISCONNECT|
```

As this makes sense, I want the openvpn server to disconnect any existing client connection with that certificate before opening a new one, therefore keeping the ip address. Is there a way to achive this? Pls Note that the dublicate-cn option doesn't work here, as it wont work together with ifconfig-pool-persist.

Answer (score 1):

For those interested, I changed from the ifconfig-pool-persist setup to a client-config-dir setup combined with a ifconfig-push statement, which finally keeps the assigend ip's stable. There are still the occasionally double connections and I have no clue why they happen. Even after adding duplicate-cn 1 option, this still happens from time to time.